# How to check priority of currently active notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am generating a notification like:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder ncBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    ncBuilder.setContentTitle("My Notification");
    ncBuilder.setContentText("You've a meeting today.");
    ncBuilder.setTicker("Please be there in the meeting.");
    ncBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
    ncBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    ncBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingNotIntent);
    ncBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    manager.notify("Notification Generator", (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), ncBuilder.build());
```

Here we can see that the priority i am setting is `PRIORITY_MAX`. But in code, when i am checking for the priority of this notification, it showing as `PRIORITY_DEFAULT`.

The code i am using to check the priority of received notification is:

```
            if (currentNos[i].getNotification().extras.getInt(String.valueOf(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)) == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Max Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (currentNos[i].getNotification().extras.getInt(String.valueOf(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)) == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN){
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Min Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (currentNos[i].getNotification().extras.getInt(String.valueOf(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)) == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW){
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Low Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (currentNos[i].getNotification().extras.getInt(String.valueOf(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)) == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH){
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is a High Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (currentNos[i].getNotification().extras.getInt(String.valueOf(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)) == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT){
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Default Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Priority for this Notification is not set.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

How can i check the priority of currently active notifications?
Can someone help me with this?

- **Note:** `currentNos` is the array of currently active notifications.

Answer (score 0):

- I was trying for this and found the answer. Hope this will help:

  ```
          if (currentNos[i].getNotification().priority == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Max Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else if(currentNos[i].getNotification().priority == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "This is a High Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else if(currentNos[i].getNotification().priority == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Default Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else if(currentNos[i].getNotification().priority == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Low Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else if(currentNos[i].getNotification().priority == NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "This is a Min Priority Notification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Priority for this Notification is not set.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
  ```